# ¿como traducir react hooks a react normal con setState?

Tags: reactjs

¿Como puedo traducir este codigo a usar `setState` normalmente?, esto usa react hooks y queria saber como puedo usarlo en una clase puesto que mi componente no es una funcion.
Alguien que domine react puede traducir este codigo facilmente pero a mi aun me cuesta.
gracias de antemano.
no quiero complicarme demasiado si es muy avanzado usar hooks en clases entonces prefiero traducir este codigo a uno normal solo react no hooks.

```js
import React, { Fragment, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Message from './message';
import Progress from './progress';

const FileUpload = () => {
    const [file, setFile] = useState("");
    const [filename, setFilename] = useState("Choose File");
    const [uploadedFile, setUploadedFile] = useState({});
    const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
    const [uploadPercentage, setUploadPercentage] = useState(0);

    const onChange = e => {
        setFile(e.target.files[0]);
        setFilename(e.target.files[0].name);
    }

    const onSubmit = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", file); // or "movieImg"

        try {
            const res = await axios.post("/img", formData, {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
                },
                onUploadProgress: progressEvent => {
                    setUploadPercentage(parseInt(Math.round((progressEvent.loaded*100)/progressEvent.total)));
                    setTimeout(() => setUploadPercentage(0), 5000);
                }               
            });

            const { filename, filepath } = res.data;
            setUploadedFile({ filename, filepath });
            setMessage("File uploaded");
        } catch(err) {
            if(err.response.status === 500) {
                setMessage("there was a problem with the server.");
            } else {
                setMessage(err.response.data.message);
            }
        }
    }

    return ( 
        <Fragment>
            {message ? <Message message={message} /> : null}
            <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                <div className="custom-file mb-4">
                    <input type="file" className="custom-file-input" id="customFile" onChange={onChange} />
                    <label className="custom-file-label" htmlFor="customFile" >
                        {filename}
                    </label>
                </div>
                <Progress percentage={uploadPercentage} />
                <input type="submit" value="Upload" className="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-4" />
            </form>
            { uploadedFile ? 
                <div className="row mt-5">
                    <div className="col-md-6 m-auto">
                        <h3 className="text-center">{ uploadedFile.filename }</h3>
                        <img style={{width: "100%"}} src={uploadedFile.filepath} />
                    </div>
                </div> : null }
        </Fragment>
     );
}
 
export default FileUpload;
```

Se que usar react hooks seria mas moderno pero me conformo con los `setState()` normales.

Comment: Esta bien que si te cuesta mucho te mantengas con la sintaxis antigua, pero te recomiendo tomarte el tiempo de aprender a usar hooks. Es bastante sencillo y esta ganando mucha popularidad. La mayoria de las librerias importantes ya lo adoptaron asique tarde o temprano conviene aprenderlo.

Comment: sip, generalmente yo lo que hago es convertir las clases en componentes funcionales, me agrada la facilidad que tiene. Pero claro es bueno saber usar ambos, para poder mantener código ya estructurado...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ya lo hice, es asi:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import http from "../services/httpService"; 
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import Progress from './progress';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

class ImageUpload extends Component {
    state = {  
        movieImg: "",
        filename: "Choose File",
        uploadedFile: {},
        uploadPercentage: 0
    }

    onImageChange = e => {
        console.log(e.target.files[0].name);

        this.setState({ 
            movieImg: e.target.files[0], 
            filename: e.target.files[0].name
        });
    }

    onSubmit = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("movieImg", this.state.movieImg);

        
        const res = await http.post("http://localhost:3900/api/img", formData, {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
            },
            onUploadProgress: progressEvent => {
                this.setState({
                    uploadPercentage: (parseInt(Math.round((progressEvent.loaded*100)/progressEvent.total)))
                });

                setTimeout(() => this.setState({uploadPercentage : 0}), 5000);
            }               
        })
        .then(res => { toast.success('upload success') })
        .catch(err => { toast.error('upload fail') });

        const { filename, filepath } = res.data;
        this.setState({uploadedFile: {filename, filepath}});
    }

    render() { 
        return (  
            <div>
                <div className="form-group">
                <ToastContainer />
                </div>
                <form onSubmit = {this.onSubmit}>
                <div className="custom-file mb-4">
                    <input name="movieImg" type="file" className="custom-file-input" id="customFile" onChange={this.onImageChange} />
                    <label className="custom-file-label" htmlFor="customFile" >
                        {this.state.filename}
                    </label>
                </div>
                <Progress percentage={this.state.uploadPercentage} />
                <input type="submit" value="Upload" className="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-4" />
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
 
export default ImageUpload;
```